# "Mean vs zero-mean" when trying to fit a best ARIMA (p,d,q) model by auto.arima

Tags: arima

I'm training how to use auto.arima in [here](http://shishirshakya.blogspot.com/2015/07/garch-model-estimation-backtesting-risk.html). But this is my results:

```
DJI.data = get.hist.quote(instrument="^DJI", start="2010-01-01",  end="2015-07-23", quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", compression="d", retclass="zoo")

plot(DJI.data, main = "DJIE Closing Prices on NASDAQ", ylab = "Price (USD)", xlab = "Date")

DJI.ret <- diff(log(DJI.data))*100

plot(DJI.ret, main = "Monthly Compound Returns", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Return in percent")

fit1 <- auto.arima(DJI.ret, trace=TRUE, test="kpss",  ic="bic")    

ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : Inf *    
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : 3707.588   
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 3745.219  
ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf    
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : 3703.33     
ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf   

Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean
```

It doesn't look like the tutorial (ARIMA(1,0,1) or ARMA(1,1) model). What am I doing wrong?

Besides, what is the difference between "ARIMA with non-zero mean" and "ARIMA with zero mean"?

Comment: can you prove that you are using same data as the tutorial ?

Comment: Yes, it's: DJI.data = get.hist.quote(instrument="^DJI", start="2010-01-01",  end="2015-07-23", quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", compression="d", retclass="zoo")

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you suppress the mean:

```
fit1 <- auto.arima(DJI.ret, trace=TRUE, test="kpss",  ic="bic",allowmean = F)
```

The "mean" *m* is a constant term in the ARMA formula. It is another parameter in the model (besides AR and MA terms).

See help for *arima()*:

> The definition used here has
>
> X[t] = a[1]X[t-1] + … + a[p]X[t-p] + e[t] + b[1]e[t-1] + … + b[q]e[t-q]
>
> Further, **if include.mean is true (the default for an ARMA model), this formula applies to X - m rather than X**